# Чтение файлов из каталога

Tags: php

В документации есть описание, как получить список файлов из определённой папки:

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        echo "$file\n";
    }
    closedir($handle); 
}
?>
```

Но что если в папке будет очень много файлов. Для этого я бы хотел сделать пагинацию и выводить на страницу, скажем, по 15 файлов. Вопрос в том, как мне используя данный пример, сделать так, чтобы в цикле мы получали не все файлы из папки, а только первые 15 файлов(или с 15 по 30, или с 30 по 45)? Фунция `readdir()` принимает только дескриптор, переданный ей посредство цикла `while`. Как сделать тоже самое, например через цикл `for($f=0;$<15;$f++){}`?

Comment: Я поначалу использовал scandir(), который возвращает массив с именами файлов и прикрутил к этому пагинацию, но потом смекнул, что в папке может быть очень много файлов. Теперь думаю, как можно целенаправленно, сосчитывать с папки конкретную область и количество файлов.

Comment: А что мешает прикрутить к `while` счетчик и в нужный момент прерывать дальнейшее чтение? Через тот же `for` все равно придется считывать следующий элемент и если `readdir` вернул `false`, тогда прерывать цикл. + если отображать 25 страницу, то перед циклом `for` придется листать `readdir` до нужного места. А через `while` сразу все в одном месте делать будете

Comment: $h = 0;
  while($h < 15) {
   echo $h;
   $h++;
  } Вот так стало быть?

Comment: Не совсем, как-то так: `$foundItem = 0; $currentItem = 0; $page = 2; $countOnPage = 5; while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)) && $foundItem < $countOnPage) { $currentItem++; if ($currentItem <= ($page - 1) * $countOnPage) { continue; } $foundItem++; echo "$file\n"; }` Т.е. пропускаете файлы до нужной позиции и только потом начинаете их считать и выводить.

Comment: Код в комментариях, конечно, просто прекрасен.

Comment: Благодарю тебя Друг мой за старания твои. В счастье и радости пребывай. Буду пробовать. Посмотрим что из этого получится.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23056/discussion-between-bopoh-and-stashappy).

Answer (score 1):

Для обхода файловой системы можно так же юзать итераторы , это очень быстро и просто :

```
//настройки пагинации
$length = 10;
$offset = 50;
//получить все файлы исключая папки
$fi = new FilesystemIterator('/var/www/www-user/data/mod-tmp' , FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS) ;
echo "count temp files :". iterator_count($fi)."\n";
//вырезать на вывод требуемый диапазон
$output = array_slice(iterator_to_array($fi), $offset , $length);
foreach ($output as $fileinfo) {
  echo $fileinfo->getFilename()."\n";
}
```

На выходе :

```
count temp files :33427
sess_m5ehe9t5c30sbo7rdbg9fonmd0
sess_e3muepq8h0vpt88t67gv453sl1
sess_tlkj3sf81n8qbg04abflrk0bt5
sess_2sv9f58rsjj4kmgp6cft188r93
sess_35mis1pm0leo6iak18m0e7tm91
sess_35qhoqmju6uqvo7euoit9guoh3
sess_gp959u51ksvio5s545qh314tb7
sess_2pp5gdets82434i1sm1ccm4jp0
sess_1pti5np3jgp5sfmb4l86c5g040
sess_nvkba1ul476deimse7bekac785
```

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее приемлемое решение в данном варианте это использование отдельной таблицы в БД для пользовательских файлов: **id | user_id | file_name**

```
SELECT `file_name` FROM `table_files` WHERE `user_id`=1234 LIMIT 0, 15
SELECT COUNT(`id`) as `numb` FROM `table_files` WHERE `user_id`=1234
```

Плюсы: удобная сортировка и скорость. А также, при желании, куча других дополнительных примочек, в виде дополнительных полей для рейтинга файла, даты добавления, флага удаления и т. д.

Отдельная благодарность пользователю [ВОРОН](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh).